# Optimizing Materialized views in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to make a materialized view in PostgreSQL which takes around 5327 sec to execute the query.I have done indexing and view has 8 columns and around 5000 rows.Can you suggest me a solution to make it more optimum?

Comment: We can't help you without seeing the table and index structure, and maybe some sample data also.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com.
Please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You need to supply the `create table` statements for all tables involved in the query including all `create index` statements, the `create materialized view` statement and the execution plan of the underlying SELECT statement generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`**. Everything as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question, do **not** post code in comments